# How to deploy typeorm with jwt app to heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jwt, typeorm

I've tried to deploy typorm app on heroku and I get this error:

```
/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:245
2020-07-01T22:24:15.596861+00:00 app[web.1]: return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
2020-07-01T22:24:15.596862+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-07-01T22:24:15.596977+00:00 app[web.1]: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
2020-07-01T22:24:15.596980+00:00 app[web.1]: src/index.ts(7,26): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'cookie-parser'. '/app/node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2020-07-01T22:24:15.596981+00:00 app[web.1]: Try `npm install @types/cookie-parser` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'cookie-parser';`
2020-07-01T22:24:15.596982+00:00 app[web.1]: src/index.ts(8,24): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'jsonwebtoken'. '/app/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
2020-07-01T22:24:15.596982+00:00 app[web.1]: Try `npm install @types/jsonwebtoken` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jsonwebtoken';
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "heroku-postgres",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.5",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
    "typescript": "3.6.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.9.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "pg": "^7.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "type-graphql": "^0.17.5",
    "typeorm": "0.2.19"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "server": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
    "web": "npm start --prefix web",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run web\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix web && npm run build --prefix web"
  }
}
```

and tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

There seems to be a problem with some of packages like cookie-parser or jsonwebtoken.
Previously I deployed typeorm/apollo/React project, but without authentication and these packages.
What should I do now?

Comment: Take a look at my project [here](https://github.com/carlocorradini/racer-server). It's written in Typescript and deployed on Heroku when a new commit to master is done. Heroku read your *package.json* and install all the dependencies and devDependencies then run *npm run build* (this command compile all your TS in JS into a build folder). After the compilation has finished Heroku runs *npm run start* OR a custom command defined in the [Procfile](https://github.com/carlocorradini/racer-server/blob/master/Procfile).

Comment: Remember: when running an application in production don't use ts-node or similar (they are meant for development purposes only) -> **Always use Node**, in this case, running the compiled js in the build folder.

Comment: I agree with @CarloCorradini, do not use ts-node in production.  I have no idea why you would but if you really, really, really want to, move your @types/* from devDependencies to dependencies.  If I recall correctly heroku does not install dev dependencies.